# $\mathcal{I} = \{X \in M_{n \times n} \mid X \text{ is invertible }\}$ is not-connected.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the set of all invertible real matrix $n \times n$. I have to prove that $\mathcal{I}$ is open and not-connected.

**My attempt:** Take any $A \in \mathcal{I}$. Puting $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$ we have that $\|A-B\| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow B \in \mathcal{I}$. Therefore $\mathcal{I}$ is open.

But I really don't know how I can show that $\mathcal{I}$ is not-connected.

Comment: Real matrices? Consider the determinant function. (It's continuous and never $0$ in $\cal I$...)

Comment: Determinant also solves the openness question: set of open matrices is exactly the preimage of an open set $\mathbb{R} - \{0\}$, thus is open.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of a connected set under a continuous map [is connected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Image_of_Connected_Space_is_Connected). Consider the image of $\mathcal{I}$ under the determinant map, as suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

For example (with real matrices)

$$\mathcal I=\left\{X\in M_{n\times n}\;/\;\det X<0\right\}\cup\left\{X\in M_{n\times n}\;/\;\det X>0\right\}$$

and for example

$$\left\{X\in M_{n\times n}\;/\;\det X<0\right\}=\Delta^{-1}(-\infty,\,0)\;,\;\;\Delta:=\text{ the determinant function}$$

and $\;\Delta\;$ is clearly continuous.